# Ajax reload captcha

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

В файле captcha.php я создаю gif изображения с помощью библиотеки GD и вывожу его в форме для отправки комментария к статье.

```
<img class ="captcha_img" src="captcha.php" />
```

Как мне обновить изображение с помощью ajax запроса?

Comment: Мне кажется, что AJAX здесь и не нужен. Просто обновите атрибут src у image.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let captchaUpdate = document.querySelector(".captcha_update"),
    captchaImg = document.querySelector(".captcha_img");

captchaUpdate.addEventListener('click', () => captchaImg.src = "captcha.php?r=" + Math.random());


/* Вывод результата в консоль */

captchaUpdate.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(captchaImg.src));
```

```html
<img class ="captcha_img" src="captcha.php" />
<button class="captcha_update">Обновить</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

При обычных настройках nginx / apache сработает и такое

```html
<img class ="captcha_img" src="captcha.php" onclick="this.src = this.src"/>
```

При клике на изображение, капча перезагрузится

Comment: Будет работать только если заголовки кэширования на сервере верно настроены.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел для себя следующее решение...

```
var unique = $.now();
$('.captcha_img').attr('src', 'captcha.php?' + unique); // перезагрузить капчу
```

Comment: А очистка свей формы как к вопросу относится?

Comment: Не относится. Убрал.

Comment: Кстати, в данном случае лучше использовать `prop`, а не `attr`.